# Prevent usage of glibc header files

Tags: c++, c, compilation, std

I want to prevent the usage of the standard libraries throughout our code in a cross platform and cross compiler manner.

The trick I was thinking of was to create dummy std files and put them with the highest priority in the include path.

Example of mock stdlib.h:

```
#ifndef __STDLIB_H_BLOCKED__
#define __STDLIB_H_BLOCKED__

#ifndef ALLOW_STDLIB_HEADER
    #error "STD headers are not allowed "
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#endif /* __STDLIB_H_BLOCKED__ */
```

But there are two problems with this solution:

1. I am not sure the compiler gives higher priority to -I directoires than the glibc include path
2. the line that includes stdlib.h will cause a loop - i need a way to include the real stdlib.h and not cause the compiler to re-include my mock header file.

Comment: If you are using gcc, you might look into `-nostdinc` and `-nostdlib`

Comment: put a symlink to the real stdlib somewhere, and call it "realstdlib.h" or something, then #include that in your above code. user includes <stdlib>, your fake one intercepts it and then includes realstdlib.h instead.

Comment: 1. If i will block it using GCC I won't be able include it with my allowed path

2. symblink is problematic because i don't know which stdlib the current platform/compiler toolchain has

Comment: Why do you ask? Why would `extern void*malloc(size_t);` be better than `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

The C language precisely states:

> > # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read:
>
> > # include  new-line

This explicitly indicates that includes identified through "" will *always* precede the ones identified through <>.

So if you explicitly use the "" inclues even for (your) stdlib.h, the compiler will always select your own instead of the system ones.